Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics Chapter 1 Problem 82 part (v)
Question: $s(r,n)$ is known as the Stirling numbers of the first kind and is defined as the amount of ways to arrange $r$ distinct objects around $n$ identical circles such that no circle is empty.  Show that $\sum_{n=0}^r s(r,n) = r!$
I have not been able to solve this problem, but I know that we must proceed by induction. So I check case $r=1$ and I obtain:
$\sum_{n=0}^1 s(1,n) = s(1,0) + s(1,1) = 0 + 1 = 1 = 1!$
Then I assume this holds for case $r=k$. So: $\sum_{n=0}^k s(k,n) = k!$
Now we consider case $r=k+1$. So we need to show that
$\sum_{n=0}^{k+1} s(k+1,n) = (k+1)!$
This is where I am completely lost. If possible, I would like to solve the problem myself so please give me a hint for solving this last inductive step. Thanks!

what is $s(a,b)$?

I edited the problem and included a definition of the Stirling numbers of the first kind

A permutation of the numbers $1,\cdots,r$ will map numbers round in circles: $v_0\to v_1\to v_2\to v_3\to \cdots\to  v_{d-1}\to v_0$.  That is a permutation of $1,\cdots,r$ tells you how to distribute the numbers $1,\cdots,r$ to circles.  Conversely, if you have numbers distributed to circles, you can recover the permutation by sending each number to number after it on its circle.  Thus the number of permutations of $1,\cdots,r$, is precisely the number of ways of assigning the numbers $1,\cdots,r$ to circles.  e.g. $r!=\sum_{n=0}^r s(r,n) $.

Well, after long hours I have figured out the definitive answer to the proof.
We proceed by induction as before. Arriving at the $r=k+1$, we need to derive a recurrence formula. It is as follows: $s(k+1,n) = s(k,n-1) + ks(k,n)$.
Now, we can use it in our sum of case $r=k+1$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{k+1} s(k+1,n)  &= \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} s(k,n-1) + ks(k,n) \hspace{0.1in} \implies \text{Follows from (1)} \\
    &= \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} s(k,n-1) + \sum_{n=0}^{k+1} ks(k,n)  \\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{k} s(k,n) + \sum_{n=0}^{k+1} ks(k,n) \\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{k} s(k,n) + \sum_{n=0}^{k} ks(k,n)\\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^{k} s(k,n) + ks(k,n) \\
    &= k+1\sum_{n=0}^k s(k,n)\\
    &= (k+1)k! \\
    &= (k+1)! \hspace{0.1in} \blacksquare
\end{align*}$$
***I have not really derived the recurrence formula since I do not understand its derivation (I basically memorized it). It is like so. Consider an object $i$ among a total of $k+1$ objects. Case one is that it is alone in a circle. There are $s(k,n-1)$ such cases. Case two is that it is with other objects in the circle. First we place the $k+1-1 (=k)$ objects in the circles according to $s(k,n)$. This is what I do not understand: Then we place object $i$ in $k+1-1(=k)$ distinct spaces to the "immediate right" of the corresponding $k$ distinct objects. Thus we obtain: $ks(k,n)$. And adding both the expressions gives the recurrence formula.

The equation $\color{red}{s(k+1,n)=(k+1)s(k,n)}$ is not correct. Instead, $s(k+1,n)=ks(k,n)+s(k,n-1)$. You can use this correct equation to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^rs(r,n)=r!$.

Hello Mike. Thank you for your help for both of my questions. However, I have one question. why $ks(k,n)$ and not $ns(k,n)$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation

This question discussed the recurrence relation in detail: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368530/stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind

Thank you very much Mike. Your help is greatly appreciated
